# Unable to Dynamically Retrieve RDS Cluster Endpoint in Terraform Provider Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I'm encountering an issue with dynamically retrieving the endpoint of an RDS cluster in my Terraform provider configuration when there is change which needs a DB destroy and recreate with updates like enabling encryption or renaming the DB.

Here's the relevant part of my Terraform configuration:

```
provider "postgresql" {
  host             = module.rds_cluster.endpoint
  port             = var.db_port
  database         = var.db_name
  username         = var.admin_user
  password         = var.admin_password
  superuser        = false
  expected_version = var.engine_version
}
```

Despite configuring `module.rds_cluster.endpoint` to fetch the RDS cluster endpoint dynamically, Terraform is substituting it with the localhost IP address instead. However, when I hardcode the endpoint, it works fine.

**Error:**

```
Error: Error connecting to PostgreSQL server  (scheme: postgres): dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused

with module.rds_cluster_db.postgresql_role.iam_user,
   on .terraform/modules/rds_cluster_db/main.tf line 103, in resource "postgresql_role" "iam_user":
  103: resource "postgresql_role" "iam_user" {
```

Error is coming from the below resource,

```
resource "postgresql_role" "iam_user" {
  name            = var.db_user
  login           = true
  roles           = ["rds_iam"]
  create_database = true
  create_role     = true
  inherit         = true

  depends_on = [
    module.rds_cluster
  ]
}
```

**Details:**

I am using,
[rds_cluster==1.3.1](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/rds-cluster/aws/1.3.1)

Terraform and Providers info:

```
Terraform v1.5.5
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/cyrilgdn/postgresql v1.22.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.4.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.41.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes v2.27.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.2.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.6.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls v4.0.5
```

Any insights in troubleshooting or fix the issue is helpful and appreciated!

**Update:**

**Module code:**

```
module "rds_cluster_db" {
  source = "github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-rds-cluster?ref=1.3.1"

  name      = "my-user-db" # can't update name, fails with the provided error

  db_user       = "db_user"
  db_name       = "db_name"
  instance_type = "db.t4g.small"

  # storage_encrypted = true # can't enable, fails with the provided error
}
```

Comment: It would also be good to understand which module you are using for creating the cluster.

Comment: @MarkoE FYI, It works fine, if I update `db_user, db_name and/or instance_type`, only fails when I try to make any change that tries to destroy and recreate like changing `name`  or enabling `storage_encryption`.

Comment: @MarkoE Update the post with the module code and error message. Can you please check now?